# MySQL method SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery

I'm a bit confused about how to use SUM() function in this case:

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE photos 
(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

And this is one of my attempts, which I know it's wrong:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(SELECT COUNT(photos.id) AS total 
        FROM users
        JOIN photos ON users.id = photos.user_id
        GROUP BY users.id);
```

I want to get the sum of the column "total". How can I do that?

Thanks for the answer, Gordon!

So now, I have another question: why I can't use `SUM()` this way?

In a situation where I would like to use SUM in a subquery, what should be possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS total
FROM users u JOIN
     photos p
     ON u.id = p.user_id;
```

That is, just count all the rows generated by the `JOIN`.

Comment: Wow! In fact, here group by is no use! Thank you!